# A question on a subset of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A$ be a nonempty open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and $B$ a dense subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Is $A+B=\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Surely you don't really mean $R$ to be the *natural* numbers?

Comment: You left out one condition: $A$ must not be empty.

Answer (score 2):

If by $R$ you mean the real numbers (more often written $\mathbb{R}$), and if $A$ is non-empty, then the answer is yes. Certainly we know that $A + B \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, so it suffices to show the other direction, that $A + B \supseteq \mathbb{R}$. To see this, take $r \in \mathbb{R}$ and $a \in A$. Since $A$ was open, let us write that $(a- \epsilon,a+\epsilon) \in A$. Then $r-a$ is another real number, and by density of $B$, we can find some $b$ within $\epsilon/2$ of $r-a$. Let us say that $b = r - a - \delta$, where $|\delta| \leq \epsilon/2$. Then by hypothesis, $a + \delta$ was in $A$, so that $(a + \delta) + b = r$, where $(a+ \delta) \in A$, $b \in B$, and we are done.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that $R=\mathbb{R}$.

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $x_0 \in A$, $\epsilon>0$ be such that $(x_0-\epsilon,x_0+\epsilon) \subset A$. There exists $x_1 \in B$ such that $|(x-x_0)-x_1|< \epsilon$, so $x \in x_1 + A \subset A+B$.